# Write a slow query to test slow query logging?

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

Is there a simple query that would take > 2 sec so that I can test the slow query logger?

I am looking for something like a generic recursive or iterative statement.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A simple query would be:

```
SELECT SLEEP(2);
```

You want to iterate it?

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `iterateSleep` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `iterateSleep` (iterations INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE remainder INT;

    SET remainder = iterations;

    read_loop: LOOP     
        IF remainder=0 THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        SELECT SLEEP(2) INTO @test;
        SET remainder = remainder - 1;          
    END LOOP;

    RETURN iterations;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

-- TO TEST IT OUT
mysql> SELECT iterateSleep(2);
+-----------------+
| iterateSleep(2) |
+-----------------+
|               2 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (4.01 sec)
```

Alternatively if you just want to test your slow_query_log, change '[long_query_time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_long_query_time)' to 0 (to log all queries):

```
SET long_query_time=0;
```

Comment: As a sidenote the equivalent for SQL Server is `WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'`

Comment: select sleep(2) is the answer that I was looking for; I can't set long_query_time myself.

Comment: Short and sweet is always neat. Nice Stored Procedure as well. +1 !!!

Comment: The `SELECT sleep(2)` didn't add anything to the slow-log - but the `SET GLOBAL long_query_time=0` gave me quick input to test. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty horrible query.  It is a Cartesian product, using non-ansi style join.

```
use master
select * from sys.objects, sys.indexes
```

Comment: neat...But I don't think that's mysql.

Comment: oops.  Sorry.  I didn't notice it was for MySQL.